# Code an Photo.app like

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, photo, image

I'm trying to code myself the Apple Photo.app for iOS.
All is good but when I select an album to see all my pictures it's a bit slow to load all my pictures. All my thumbnail are saved in a database. I manage them with Core Data.
So when I select an album I create a specific request and add all my thumbnail in a scrollview. But I have to wait to see all my thumbnail. 
In Photos.app when I select an album all pictures are directly loaded.

How has Apple improved that ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What image format are you using? If you play with Apple's photo app, its lightening fast even if you continue to scroll large numbers of pictures. It is definitely not caching these images. Try to make them as tiny as possible, and it should work as expected.

Comment: I'm using JPEG Compression for my image data (0.5). And I'm adding these thumbnail as subclass of UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using `UITableViewCells` with 4 images in each, and that you are recycling the cells.

JPEGs take a lot of decompression CPU cycles. There was a specific mention of this at Apple's recent developer conference. Most likely this is what is slowing you down.

**Solution**: use PNGs and make sure they are absolutely optimized for the size and resolution that is are the minimum requirements for the thumbnail images. Core data should be fast enough to provide smooth scrolling for thousands of thumbnail images.

Comment: For the moment I'm not using UITableViewCell. So your solution is to create a TableView and then custom tableviewcell. You're right. If I have 1000 images it's better. for your solution I don't understand "Core data should be fast enough to provide smooth scrolling for thousands of thumbnail images.". I must request CD each time I'm scrolling down ?

Comment: Basically, yes. The images are loaded in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and while the cells and imageViews are recycled, the images have to be loaded from the database whenever a cell is needed.

Comment: Ok but how can i write this request ?

Comment: The same way you are extracting the images from your database now.

Comment: The problem is that I'm loading all images in one time

Comment: Try that on your device (rather than simulator). My guess is it will crash with thousands of images. Use an entity in your core data database that keeps track of the order of the images and use that to retrieve them.

Comment: Ok so some sort of primary key? Or perhaps is there a way to fetch 0 to 10 then 10 to 20 etc ..

Comment: Yes, you can index your order number attribute. Also, for each cell you need exactly the next 4 images.

Comment: So I just tried your solution for PNG and the seep is the same. It's slow. I'm just loading 8 images (one in a single tableview cell) :/

Comment: @Mundi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2814/discussion-between-pierre-and-mundi)